# adjust height of select list to fit in the popup

Tags: html

I have a select list in a popup with 53 options in it. The number of options may vary. When I click the select list the drop down opens and the options are getting displayed. But the drop down exceeds the popup and reaches the border of the screen and scrollbar is available. I am looking to reduce the height of the drop down so that it fits inside the popup. I have already tried with the size attribute. But it turns the select list to look like a list. Is there a way to achieve this?

My HTML is as follows

```
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="dropdownfield" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label">Test 
Field</label>
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
<select class="form-control" id="test">
<option *ngFor="let x of test[value]="x.id">{{x.value}}</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: provide css or  u r using Bootstrap version ?

Comment: r u using Bootstrap modal js .. please provide complete code in jsfiddle